# geting information about the distribution of the maximum distance from a fixed starting point (0,0)

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, simulation

I have created a program that simulates a random walk, and stores the max distance in a list. The number of steps is generated randomly. I am trying to produce data about the distribution of the maximum distance from the fixed starting point (median, mean, variance etc.). However, I believe I am doing it very wrong.

Code:

```
walk_seed = 2025678

num_steps = 500 + 10 * (walk_seed % 11) - 50

np.random.seed(walk_seed)

journeys = 20000

max_distance = np.zeros(journeys)

for j in range(journeys):
    x_c = 0
    y_c = 0
    max_x = 9
    max_y = 6
    current_max_distance = math.sqrt(max_x**2+max_y**2)
    
    for i in range(num_steps):
        
        direction = np.random.randint(0,3)
        
        if direction == 0:
            x_c += 1
        if direction == 1:
            x_c -= 1
        if direction == 2:
            y_c += 1
        if direction == 3:
            y_c -= 1
            
        current_distance = math.sqrt(x_c * x_c + y_c * y_c)
        current_distance_round = math.trunc(current_distance)
        # print(current_distance_round)
        
        if current_distance_round > current_max_distance:
            current_max_distance = current_distance_round 
            
            
    max_distance[j] = current_distance_round
```

In total, there are 20000 walks, all with a fixed number of steps and a max distance. Currently, if the current distance is greater than the max distance, it will store it in the list. However, the max distance seems to be irrelevant as the numbers I am getting are too big (mean = 160, variance = 107).

Comment: By what basis are you jusdging that the numbers you are getting are "too big"?  What is the expected output?

Comment: Your implementation looks fine to me, perhaps you might want to ask [stats.se] for sanity check before coming to us looking for a bug that might not exist.